# implementing a plugin in the Eclipse Workbench

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin

I am a newbie to eclipse plugin development. I want to implement a plugin that when selected opens a sidebar in the workbench. The sidebar should contain a search text box whose input is captured by the plugin and the output based on that is displayed below the text box.
I shall be grateful to anyone who can provide me with directions on how to get started and set up to implement such a plugin in the eclipse workbench, like what are the extensions I'll need to implement etc.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This book is the standard reference: [http://www.amazon.com/Eclipse-Plug-ins-3rd-Eric-Clayberg/dp/0321553462](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0321553462)

Answer (score 0):

you probably want to implement a (sticky) view. And this should help get started http://www.eclipse.org/articles/viewArticle/ViewArticle2.html

Once you are sure about it let you more specific questions come.